# How to parse content within HTML tags in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This is how I am storing data in mongoDB:

```
{
   "question": {
       "en": "<p>Durand Cup is associated with the game of ?</p>\n",
       "hn": ""
    }
}
```

Now I need to sort these questions alphabetically by `question.en`. When I use regular `sort()` method from mongoose, sorting is not done properly because HTML tags are present in the string.

I need a way to parse the content between HTML tags, so that I can sort it alphabetically.

**For example:**
After parsing above `question.en` I should get

```
question: {
   "en": "Durand Cup is associated with the game of ?",
   "hn": ""
}
```

Now I will want to sort `question.en` alphabetically. That is, I don't want HTML tags to affect sorting.

Comment: Please elaborate. Sorting alphabetically will still work even if they all start with the same `<p>`. Is the issue that some do and some don't?

Comment: If you are using an aggregate pipeline you could potentially remove the leading tag with [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/), assuming they are always <p> or something with similar characters. Otherwise it might benefit to store the data again without the html (to allow for sorting) or sort in-memory in your app. That's assuming you can make those decisions.